# Qt QMediaPlayer/Phonon video playing

Tags: c++, qt, video, qmediaplayer

I have a Video Player starting from version Qt 4.7 using phonon.

Upgrading the player with new versions of Qt (5.1 at the moment), I noticed that Qt
is able to play less and less videos (mostly avi).

Error you get with 5.1 is serious "resource error", with - as I said some videos. Other will play fine.
It turns out that phonon was able to play much more videos correctly than the current version.

The questions I have:

Does anybody know anything about this?
Do you think that changing over to the OpenGL version might help?
Do you think that building the source from scratch might help (which by the way I have done with 5.0, but it could still play less videos than phonon, so I hadn't bothered doing this with Qt 5.1)?